# How do I insert a checkbox into a bit type database column .Net?

Tags: .net, sql-server

So I'm trying to insert a checkbox value into a database bit type database column using .Net and MSSQL using SQL Data source. Doing it like so (codebehind):

```
sqlInsert.InsertParameters["company"].DefaultValue = blCompanyName.Text;
sqlInsert.InsertParameters["email"].DefaultValue = lblEmailName.Text;
sqlInsert.InsertParameters["Jan25"].DefaultValue = CheckBox1.Checked;
sqlInsert();
```

Then on the sql datasource I have:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="sqlInsert" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:webadsConnectionString %>"
  InsertCommand="INSERT MYTABLE (company,email,Jan25,) VALUES (@company,@email,@Jan25,)" >
<InsertParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="company" />            
  <asp:Parameter Name="email" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="Jan25" Type="Boolean" />
</InsertParameters>
```

Any ideas how to go about achieving this? Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can edit your own question - the edit link is under the tags (currently ".net" and "sql-server")

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind this worked out. My problem was with the database not the code.